# Why Layer detection isn't possible in Autodesk forge Api for PDF files?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I want to import PDF file in Model derivative API and work with different layers. But it is not detecting layers in PDF models as it does in DWG files. Layer manager option is not visible. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where the Model Derivative service isn't extracting enough information from your input files, you have a couple of options:

- if your input file is a AutoCAD, Revit, Inventor, or 3ds Max file, consider extracting the additional information using the Design Automation service
- if your input file is a PDF, consider:

  - viewing the PDF directly in the viewer (see this [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/fast-pdf-viewingmarkup-inside-forge-viewer) for more details)
  - using a 3rd party library (e.g., [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)) to extract the additional info yourself

Comment: Also, feel free to shoot us an email to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` so that we can submit a feature request to the Model Derivative team, and inform you of the progress.